# ModelBuilder split and delete line segments over x length

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have a Polyline created from a table, most of the points are within 5 feet of each other but between sets of points there is at least 20 ft without points. How can I remove or split/delete those longer segments of lines without editing manually? I'm using ModelBuilder now and will have to apply this model to different datasets and locations in the future.

[image: LineSegments]

Answer (score 1):

**With Advanced License**

If you have the Advanced license, then you can use the '[Split Line At Vertices](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm)' tool to split the line into its segments.  (This is the tool that required the Advanced license.)

Then you can select all the segments that are longer than 6ft (or whatever length you decide for your threshold) and DELETE them.

Then '[Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm)' the remaining line segments, being sure to

- Check the 'Unsplit Lines' parameter
- Uncheck the 'Allow multipart features' parameter

**Without Advanced License**

If you do not have the Advanced license, you can use Python to manually split the geometry every time the distance between two consecutive vertices is greater than your threshold length.  This gets more complicated and is not really a Model Builder solution, so I've not included details here.

There are some alternatives to the 'Split Line At Vertices' tool described at:
[Splitting lines at vertices in ArcGIS Desktop with Basic level license?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83716/splitting-lines-at-vertices-in-arcgis-desktop-with-basic-level-license)